# Can't find "Add App" button for already created view only Firebase project

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-console

I was added to a firebase project by my team member. The project is view only. The android app for the project has already been added and I'm trying to add the iOS app to the project, but I can't find the Add App button as shown below. I tried it on Google chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
[image]

Based on [Ray Wenderlich's updated Firebase tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2), there should be a button in the top right as shown below. Where is the Add App button and how do I add my iOS app to this project?
[image]

Comment: on what browser are you seeing this? You should try google chrome.

Comment: I tried it on Google chrome, firefox, and safari and I still don't see the button.  My project is view only, would that make a difference? Could it be a permissions setting?

Comment: Ohhh I See! its because you have been added by someone else and you don't have the privilege to create a new project.

Comment: I have added it as an answer, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you are not the administrator of the account, and you don't have project creation privileges.

Comment: Indeed. View only means just that.